# Kusto Query - using case() and range() to group results

Tags: syntax, azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to group existing error codes into categories (example: codes from 101 to 118 belong to one service, from 201 to 213 to another) and to count the number of error codes by category.

I have used the case function and inside of it I used range for the error codes, and it works well, except for some reason it shows error code 004 as part of the "Other" case. Why is this happening?

```
| extend codeRange = case(Code in (range(001, 004, 1)), "GeneralMessages",
                      Code in (range(101, 118, 1)), "TransactionProcessing",
                      Code in (range(201, 213, 1)), "RulesExecution",
                      Code in (range(301, 335, 1)), "MerchantRefData",
                      Code in (range(401, 403, 1)), "BinProcessing",
                      Code in (range(501, 505, 1)), "ExchangeRateProcessing",
                      Code in (range(601, 603, 1)), "DecisionRouting",
                      Code in (range(701, 709, 1)), "TransactionRegistry",
                      Code in (range(801, 805, 1)), "ClientScore",
                      Code in (range(901, 903, 1)), "PayEngineConfig",
                      Code in (range(1001, 1003, 1)), "SecureService",
                      Code in (range(1101, 1108, 1)), "ProxyAPI", 
                      "Other")
| project ErrorFrom, Message, Code, operation_Id, codeRange
```

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQwva.png)

The expected result is that the codeRange for Code 004 will be set as GeneralMessages, not Other.

Answer (score 1):

Are you comparing it to the string "004"? The range function will create an array of numbers with the values from 1 to 4 (including 4) so if you compare to to the string "004" it will not find it.

Try to cast the error code to int:

```
print range(001, 004, 1)
| mv-expand print_0
| where print_0 == toint("004")
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used something similar, and trimmed the "00" from the string using trim_start(), and it worked.

Comment: cast to int will probably be faster